# Can I parallelize my program?

Tags: cuda, fortran, parallel-processing

This is my program:

```
program test
implicit none
integer n,m,k,i,j,Errorflag
real :: Yabs(39,39),angle(39,39)
real ,dimension(67,1) :: deltaA,A
real :: V(1,39),d(1,39),v1(29,1),d1(38,1),Ps(1,38),Qs(1,39),Jac(67,67),invJac(67,67)
real :: B1(1,38),B2(1,29),MF(1,67),trnsMF(67,1),P0(1,39),Q0(1,39)
real, dimension(38,38) :: dia1,offdia1,J1
real, dimension(29,29) :: dia2,dia3,dia4,offdia4,J4
real,dimension(38,29) ::offdia2,J2
real,dimension(29,38) ::offdia3,J3
real p,p1,q,q1

n=39;m=9
MF(1,1)=10

open(unit=3,file="ybus.dat",status="old")
open(unit=4,file="angle.dat",status="old")
 do i=1,39
        read(3,*) Yabs(i,1:39)
        read(4,*)angle(i,1:39)
    end do
close(3)
close(4)

open(unit=5,file="activepower.dat",status="old")
open(unit=8,file="reactivepower.dat",status="old")


read(5,*)Ps(1,1:38)
read(8,*)Qs(1,1:29)


close(5)
close(8)

do i=1,67
deltaA(i,1)=0
end do
v1(1:29,1)=1
d1(1:38,1)=0 
A(1:38,1)=d1(1:38,1)
A(39:67,1)=v1(1:29,1)
!call cpu_time(t1)

do while(maxval(abs(MF))>0.0001)

V(1,1)=0.982
V(1,2:30)=v1(1:29,1)
V(1,31)=1.03
V(1,32)=0.9831           
V(1,33)=1.0123
V(1,34)=0.9972
V(1,35)=1.0493
V(1,36)=1.0635 
V(1,37)=1.0278
V(1,38)=1.0265
V(1,39)=1.0475
d(1,1)=0
d(1,2:39)=d1(1:38,1)
 ! % % % %------Active Power Calculation-----%
p1=0;p=0
do i=2,n
    do j=1,n
        p1=(V(i)*V(j)*Yabs(i,j)*cos(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j)))
        p=p1+p
     end do
     P0(i-1)=p
     p=0
end do
! % % % %------Reactive Power Calculation-----%  
p=0;p1=0
do i=2,(n-m)
      do j=1,n
p1=-(V(i)*V(j)*Yabs(i,j)*sin(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j)))
p=p1+p
      end do
      Q0(i-1)=p
      p=0
end do
!!!!!!!!!!!mismatch factor
do i=1,(n-1)
   B1(i)=Ps(i)-P0(i)
  end do
do i=1,(n-m-1)
   B2(i)=Qs(i)-Q0(i)
end do

MF(1,1:38)=B1(1,1:38)
MF(1,39:67)=B2(1,1:29)
!!!!!!!!jacobian calculation for preddictor step
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!dia of j1
p=0;p1=0
do i=2,n
    do j=1,n
       if(j .ne. i)then
 p1=V(i)*V(j)*Yabs(i,j)*sin(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j))
 !print*,p1
 p=p1+p
       end if

    end do
    i=i-1
    dia1(i,i)=p

    p=0
    i=i+1
end do

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!off dia. of j1
q=0;q1=0;
do k=2,n
 i=k
    do j=2,n
        if(j .ne. i)then
        q1=V(i)*V(j)*Yabs(i,j)*sin(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j))
        end if
        i=i-1;j=j-1
offdia1(i,j)=-q1
q1=0
i=i+1;j=j+1
    end do
end do
do i=1,38
do j=1,38
J1(i,j)=offdia1(i,j)+dia1(i,j)
end do
end do
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!dia. of j2
p=0;p1=0
do i=2,(n-m)
    do j=1,n
       if(j .ne. i)then
         p1=V(j)*Yabs(i,j)*cos(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j))
 p=p1+p
       end if

    end do

    dia2(i-1,i-1)=p+(2*V(i)*Yabs(i,i)*cos(angle(i,i)))
    p=0;

end do
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!off dia. of j2
p1=0;
do k=2,n
 i=k
    do j=2,(n-m)
        if(j .ne. i)then
       p1=V(i)*Yabs(i,j)*cos(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j));
        end if
        i=i-1;j=j-1
offdia2(i,j)=p1
    p1=0;
    i=i+1;j=j+1
    end do
end do
do i=1,(n-m-1)

   offdia2(i,i)=dia2(i,i)

end do
J2=offdia2
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!dia. of j3
p=0;p1=0
do i=2,(n-m)
    do j=1,n
       if(j .ne. i)then
          p1=V(i)*V(j)*Yabs(i,j)*cos(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j))
 p=p1+p;
       end if
    end do
    i=i-1;
    dia3(i,i)=p
    p=0;
    i=i+1;
 end do
 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!off dia of j3
p=0;p1=0
do k=2,(n-m)
 i=k;
    do j=2,n
        if(j .ne. i)then
    p1=V(i)*V(j)*Yabs(i,j)*cos(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j))
        end if
     i=i-1;j=j-1
    offdia3(i,j)=-p1;
    p1=0;
    i=i+1;j=j+1
    end do
end do
do i=1,(n-m-1)
      offdia3(i,i)=dia3(i,i)

end do
J3=offdia3
!!!!!!!!!!dia of j4
p=0;p1=0
do i=2,(n-m)
    do j=1,n
       if(j .ne. i)then
           p1=V(j)*Yabs(i,j)*sin(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j))
 p=p1+p
       end if

    end do

    dia4(i-1,i-1)=-(2*V(i)*Yabs(i,i)*sin(angle(i,i)))-p
    p=0;p1=0
end do
 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!off dia of j4
p1=0;p=0
do k=2,(n-m)
 i=k;
    do j=2,(n-m)
        if(j .ne. i)then
       p1=V(i)*Yabs(i,j)*sin(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j))
        end if
    i=i-1;j=j-1
    offdia4(i,j)=-p1
    p1=0;
    i=i+1;j=j+1
    end do
 end do
 do i=1,(n-m-1)
offdia4(i,i)=dia4(i,i);
 end do
J4=offdia4
!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!formation of final jacobian!!!!!!!!!!
Jac( 1:38, 1:38) = J1 (1:38,1:38)
Jac( 1:38,39:67) = J2 (1:38,1:29)
Jac(39:67, 1:38) = J3 (1:29,1:38)
Jac(39:67,39:67) = J4 (1:29,1:29)
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!print*,Jac(23,21)
CALL FindInv(Jac,invJac ,67, ErrorFlag)
trnsMF=transpose(MF)

deltaA=matmul( invJac, trnsMF)
do i=1,67
A(i)=A(i)+deltaA(i)
end do

!!!!!!!!!!!!updating values
do i=1,(n-1)
    d1(i)=A(i)
end do

k=0
do i=n,(2*n-2-m)
    k=1+k
    v1(k)=A(i)
end do
end do

end program test
```

The array "Ps" contains some values. Now if I increase value of Ps(15) by Ps(15)+1 so for both values can I parallelize this code to get answer quickly.

I am using PGI compiler for CUDA FORTRAN.

Comment: I can appreciate that user991852's question was somewhat ambiguous and poorly worded.  However, I am disappointed that so many people are voting him/her down while giving no feedback as to why.  To me that's a real jerk move.  StackOverflow is really getting pretty mean and vindictive these days, in that veteran users are lashing out and beginners' questions, without giving them helpful feedback, in many cases.  The CUDA questions section seems particularly harsh.  Okay, it's a poorly worded question, but give him/her some feedback, for crying out loud...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fairly straightforward with lots of independent parallel loops.  These parallel loops appear to be wrapped in an outer convergence `do while` loop, so as long as you keep the data on the device for all iterations of the convergence loop, you won't be bottlenecked by transfers.

I would recommend starting with compiler directives for this code rather than diving in to CUDA Fortran.  Compiler directives work well for simple independent loops like these -- they are simple hints that you place in code comments that tell the compiler which loops to parallelize, which data to copy, etc.

You can first try [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/) to accelerate to multiple CPU cores.  Then you can use GPU directives such as [OpenACC](http://www.openacc-standard.org), which is going to be available soon in compilers from PGI, Cray, and CAPS.  To get a head start, you could download a free trial of the [PGI compiler](http://pgroup.com) and use their ["Accelerator"](http://www.pgroup.com/resources/accel.htm) directives.  Accelerator is very similar in syntax to OpenACC.

Comment: If OP is already using PGI CUDA compiler, then ACC is probably indeed the best choice. There is a competing standard, `OpenHMPP` which is already quite advanced, by CAPS and Pathscale.

Comment: i am using PGI compiler 

i am confused that when i should use "CUDA FORTRAN" programming for parallelization & when i should use "PGI accelerator directives" for parallelization

Comment: My suggestion is you should start with directives on your existing loops, and see how you go with that.  PGI has lots of examples on the accelerator page.  You are likely to be able to get higher performance by using CUDA Fortran, but it will require more effort/code changes, which is why I think directives are a smart place to start out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `PGI compiler` to write CUDA kernels and make CUDA API calls.

[PGI Fortran CUDA Homepage](http://www.pgroup.com/resources/cudafortran.htm)

The question, I think, you mean to ask is "**Should** I parallelize this code?"

My answer would be that yes you could see some mild benefits to parallelization, at a glance.

For example, segments like:

```
 do i=2,n
    do j=1,n
       if(j .ne. i)then
 p1=V(i)*V(j)*Yabs(i,j)*sin(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j))
 !print*,p1
 p=p1+p
       end if

    end do
    i=i-1
    dia1(i,i)=p

    p=0
    i=i+1
end do
```

Are an N^2 set of independent calculations (in this case you set n=39, but I assume it could change).  Thus you're dealing with at least a couple hundred calculations.  While ideally you'd want even MORE calculations in terms of parallelization, you're at least in good shape in terms of that many of your loops appear to be doing identical independent work @ each step -- ideal for a threaded application.

Thus you could see some mild benefit to writing CUDA kernels to replace your looping code segments in your data post-processing algorithms.  Beware, the latencies of the PCI bus in terms of memory transfers do nullify some of the performance gains, particularly for small systems.

Thus I would say, yes, by all means you can and should try this if you're game, but don't expect it to be 100x faster... maybe like 2-10x faster, if you code it well, depending on your loop bound size and level of divergence within the particular loops.

Worst case scenario you see no gains, or even see slowdown, but at least you've learned something!!

Comment: thanks for reply...actually my question is i want to run this code in parallel for different values of array Ps.

Comment: I think you need to look at the big picture.  Using a CUDA kernel to increment an array -- even a large one -- is almost certainly going to SLOW your code when the latencies are considered.  That said your code is heavily loop driven, so I would say it looks like a strong candidate for CUDA kernels -- but I would recommend a full port could give you benefits, as outlined above.